# How can I hide a document library from search results without disabling search within the document library?

Tags: document-library, search, settings

I have some document libraries that I wish to use for file archival purposes for older files that don't need to be accessed on a daily basis, but still need to be kept for posterity. Because these files don't need to be regularly accessed, I'd like to hide them from showing up in searches across the whole site collection, so that they don't clog up the search.

I found a setting to disable the items in the document library from showing up in search results in the advanced settings for the document library: [image]

However, setting this option to "no" also disables search from working within the document library after a couple of moments. This makes it impossible to find files within search disabled document libraries when the need arises.

Is there any means of hiding the contents of a document library from a site collection wide search while still having search available within the document library?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options. The easy solution is to secure the document library. People who do not have access will not see the documents in search results. The other, more complicated option, is to add an exclusion to the default search result source. This will have a broader impact, though I haven't tested the impact on the library search box.

Comment: By secure the document library, you mean limit the permissions? That won't work, because for the people who still have access to it, search results will still be clogged up for them with archived documents. That other solution sounds worth testing out though; how do I exclude something from the default search result source?

Comment: You might also try demoting the site in Search Administration under "Authoritative Pages". Creating and managing Content Sources can be done in Search Administration for the tenant or at the site collection level. The challenge is going to be Microsoft Search. I am not certain that those results will change.